# Spring Social Twitter searching by tweet id?

Tags: spring, twitter, twitter4j, spring-social

I am trying todo something pretty simple and return a tweet by its id, however I cannot find anyway in the API to actually do this? Am I just being dumb or is this not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try TimelineOperations.getStatus(tweetId).

Comment: Works a treat, thank you! Not sure why this is documented more clearly.